# A minor bug with linking

Tags: bug, status-completed

SE has this cool feature which allows you to link to specific comments etc.

The standard share button, everyone knows about and it looks like this.

[image]

You can also link comments like below by copying the link expressed here. The encircled text is a hyperlink that you can copy and paste.

[image]

Except that if you copy and paste that link while in the midst of a review session you get an incorrectly formatted link that leads to nowhere.

[Here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/24067#comment162570_82873) is the link for that comment from within a review session of "low quality posts"

and 
[Here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/82873/what-reason-of-made-tdmi32bit-tumb16bit-jazell8bit-on-at91sam7x-microcont#comment162570_82873) is a the proper link to that comment.

Printing the links out you can see where things go awry:

Bad:

"https://electronics.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/24067#comment162570_82873"

Good:

"[Why does AT91SAM7X microcontroller have different instruction modes?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/82873/what-reason-of-made-tdmi32bit-tumb16bit-jazell8bit-on-at91sam7x-microcont#comment162570_82873)"

As an aside:  This is not to call attention to a particular post, just simply using it as an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code was assuming that comments were showing on the question page only.

I have amended the link to actually go to that page if not already on it.

Will be with you the next build (rev 2013.9.20.1027).

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! It was a minor irritation but the fix is appreciated.